# python global variable can be changed on its own but not when put inside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, reference

I'm making an evolution simulator using python 3.8.1 in windows 10.
In the code a matrix called temperatures (storing temperature of every cell in the world matrix) is imported and initialised to contain only 0s, it is also never called in the code except for where the problem arose.

```
world_data = load_progress()
## other parameters ##
temperatures = world_data["temperatures"]
```

code to import the matrix ^^

```
def late_update():
    global temperatures

    ## other updates ##

    for row in temperatures:
        for tempr in row:
            tempr += 1
```

function where the matrix is modified ^^

```
while run:

    ## just some keyboard controls ##

    update()
    late_update()
    updateGFX()
```

mainloop ^^

(as you can see the temperatures are the last to be updated because updateGFX updates another matrix)

If i exit the mainloop and check the value of temperatures every unit in the matrix is 0 (whenever i kill the code) instead of a positive number. Whereas if i print the output like this :

```
for row in temperatures:
    for tempr in row:
        tempr += 1
        print(tempr)
```

in the console only 1s will appear (i waited 20 minutes and checked so i'm quite sure) pointing out that right after the loop the temperatures will reset (also if i print the matrix after the loop it's just 0 so it's confirmed).

I tried to update temperatures directly in the mainloop outside late_update but it was the same.

I also tried making a copy of the matrix with the copy module like this:

```
temperatures_copy = copy.deepcopy(temperatures)
for row in temperatures_copy:
    for tempr in row:
        tempr += 1
temperatures = copy.deepcopy(temperatures_copy)
```

Then literally before posting the question i remembered about list comprehensions and changed the code to:

```
temperatures = [[tempr + 1 for tempr in row] for row in temperatures]
```

and it worked.

Since this may be also a problem for future development though, i'll still ask the question about
**why a list matrix can't be modified in an annidated loop (inside another loop) but can be if the annidated loop is turned into a list comprehension**.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: `tempr` is not a reference to the list element, it just gets its value. Incrementing `tempr` doesn't change the list.

Comment: Temperatures does not reset after loop, but, when you call `for tempr in row` tempr is a copy of the element in row. so it's not changing the value inside the original array, same with loop comprehension but, there you are rewriting the array with `temperatures =...`

Comment: @UlisesBussi Not quite. No copy is being made, `tempr` references the _exact same object_ as the element in the row. The issue is that `tempr += 1` rebinds `tempr` to refer to a different object. Rebinding `tempr` has no influence on the reference held by the row.

Comment: @Barmar to be clear, it is a reference to the exact same object in the list.

Comment: @UlisesBussi no, it is *not a copy*